# How to append output of currently editing script in vim?

Tags: vim

for example

I have a ruby script

```
puts "something will be inserted at the EOF"
```

after save this script. 
the script content should be:

```
puts "something will be inserted at the EOF"
# something will be inserted at the EOF
```

If I change output string It will replace the old line(s)

finally, my connected pieces

```
function Rb_append_output()
    augroup RbAppendOutput
        autocmd!
        " strip the old comments 
        autocmd! BufWritePre <buffer> g/#=>/,$ d
        " append the script's output at EOF
        autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer> $r ! ruby % | sed 's/^/\#=> /'
    augroup END
    echom "Ruby Append Output Active!"
endfunction
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried, where are you struggling with?! By showing us your (failed) efforts, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer.

Comment: firstly, I came up with `:r! ruby script.rb`. the problems are .. 1. I had to move the cursor at EOF for output insertion. 2. I had no idea about remove the output after save. Now I am trying to follow your answer. Thanks again. sorry for lately replay :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute the current buffer in an external shell via

```
:! %
```

The `%` stands for the current buffer name. The `:read` command allows to add content from a file or external command into the buffer. Combine the two, and you'll get a command that appends the output of the current buffer's execution to the buffer:

```
:$read !%
```

The added range can be accessed via the range `:'[,']`, which you can put before a `:substitute` command to insert the comment prefix, which based on your example you want to have.

To trigger this after each buffer write, use

```
:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> ...
```

Now, the only thing left for you to do is put the pieces together, and implement the deletion of the previously inserted contents. (If you can identify those via the comment prefixes, that's a `:delete` command, e.g. `$;?^#\@!?+1,$delete`.)